# Variable or uniform acceleration, does it matter?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration

I got an object that accelerates from speed 0m/s to 10m/s in 2 seconds, after achieving maximum speed it continues moving for another 2 seconds and then stops.

Now, will the distance traveled be different if:

- attempt 1: the acceleration is uniform.
- attempt 2: the acceleration is not uniform.

Considering that the maximum speed is always reached at 2 seconds, it is intuitive to assume that the distance traveled would be equal, however I got doubts and I forgot how to physics.

Comment: Imagine an extreme case where it is at rest for 1.99 seconds.

Comment: The distance traveled is equal to the area under the velocity vs. time curve.  Try drawing the curves for different scenarios.

Comment: Oh, I remembered now!, thanks. So as a side-question, what is the "best" acceleration to cover most distance?.

Comment: You didn't say whether the velocity curve must be monotonic (acceleration always positive).  If you allow the particle to accelerate to _more_ than 10 m/s, in the first two seconds, but then slow down to 10 m/s for the final two seconds, then there is no upper bound on how far it could travel (ignoring special relativity).

Comment: The acceleration is monotonic, yes, considering 0 is also a valid value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your follow-on question is, find the acceleration profile that will completely fill the area under the velocity/time curve from 0 < t < 2 seconds and 0 < v < 10 m/s.  It's the extreme case that covers the opposite end of the scale from garyp's suggestion.